# Is it common to conduct technical test for project manager (IT projects) interview?

Tags: interview

I have been requested to attend 'some' technical test while I applying a job for PM position which is unusual in Singapore. This is fuzz. Am I hired to do coding like a developer?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way for us to know whether you are expected to code. You will have to ask that specific company.

Comment: At the interview, ask how hands-on the role is expected to be in terms of coding. I did that recently at an interview for a "manager" position and learned that I would essentially be half of the IT department and responsible for a lot of development.

Answer (score 2):

I know companies like Microsoft, Google and Apple who do this assessments. Other companies I've worked for also do it.

Don't think of it as "I'm going to be coding" but rather... "I'll be managing coding projects hence I need to understand them".

I personally think it's useful to have technical knowledge for two reasons:

- It helps you understand deadlines, difficulties or even provide a helping hand for proposing solutions.
- It facilitates trust building around your decisions because they can be considered well founded.

Compare with PM:SE question [How technical should a Project Manager be?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/55/32641).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good PM, some kind of technical test should be included in the assessment. Knowledge of and feeling for technology makes an immense difference.